# Underline with transition

Tags: html, css

I would like the text to underline when I hover over it, with a slight transition to make it look nice, but it underlines directly and the transition doesn't occur, what's my mistake?

```css
.habilidades__titulo {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: var(--branco-principal);
}

.habilidades__titulo:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  transition: 2s all;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="habilidades__titulo">
  title
</a>
```

Comment: please include all your codes, so that others are not confused to help

Comment: What sort of transition are you wanting? I had assumed you would want the line to expand from left to right on hover but others have interpreted the requirement as the color slowly fading in.

Answer (score 1):

### Issue

This problem is caused by CSS transition. Transition doesn't work for values that cannot be represented numerically: `auto`, `display: none/block/flex`, etc.

`text-decoration: none` <-> `underline` is NOT numerical. That is why your code doesn't work.

More examples:

- ❌height: 0 <-> height: auto
- ❌display: none <-> display: flex
- ✅height: 0 <-> height: 100vh
- ✅color: blue <-> color: red (Colors CAN be represented numerically)

### Solution

Change `text-decoration-color` instead of `text-decoration-line`(= text-decoration in your code)

```css
.habilidades__titulo {
  text-decoration-color: transparent; /* rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: var(--branco-principal);
  transition: 2s all; /* Moved */
}

.habilidades__titulo:hover {
  text-decoration-color: inherit; /* The same color as font-color */
  /* transition: 2s all; */
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="habilidades__titulo">
  title
</a>
```

Comment: Transition fails when you unhover. Put transition on the element & not the hover

Answer (score 0):

Use border instead and apply the transition on the border color.

```css
.habilidades__titulo {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: red;
  transition: 2s border;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid transparent;
}

.habilidades__titulo:hover {
  border-color: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="habilidades__titulo">
  title
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your text-decoration color to 'transparent'. Then on hover you can set the color to whatever you want. Transition should target text-decoration-color.

```css
.habilidades__titulo {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 48px;
    color: var(--branco-principal);
    display: inline-block;
    transition: .4s text-decoration-color ease;
}

.habilidades__titulo:hover {
    text-decoration-color: darkorchid;
}
```

```html
<div class="habilidades__titulo">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very hacky. You might want to wrap it inside a div with fixed width.

```css
.habilidades__titulo {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: red;
  display:inline-block;
  width:0px;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid red;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.habilidades__titulo:hover {
  width:90px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="habilidades__titulo">
  title
</a>
```